# Switch or Jumper or Relay?

Tags: switches, relay, jumper

I have already asked this question but again I am asking it with a clear view. As u can see in the diagram attached I need to divert power coming from inverter. I want to maintain the power flow either through the short circuit line or through inductor using switch, Relay or jumpers.
[image]

I have thought about doing it with switch but then I thought It is difficult to find out the switch with this rated current.

(Good thing is I do not switch when the system is working)

When I looked about the jumpers I could not find it with higher rating. I found some power connecters but I am not sure how to use it.

But jumpers seem cost effective and also consume less space.

I found many relays which is rated for my application but the size are very big. I think I have to use min of 800V rating Relay just to be on safer side because of the voltage spike.

Please suggest out of 3, which way is best suitable for this application. U can suggest any other ways like any connectors which would do the job with less losses. Thank you

Comment: Im sorry, Do you intend to automate the switching process or you want to switch it manually? Coz if so, whats your plan with Switch and Jumpers? Use Solid State Relay either ways, Much reliable.

Comment: Yes I intend to do it manually. I thought of using pin headers just to manipulate the power flow. Is that a bad choice?

Comment: You talk about voltage, but jumpers and switches and relays all have current limitations also.  Also, not sure what "L10Amy" means.

Comment: I noticed you have a huge current draw of 40A, if that is accurate, dont use Relays or Jumpers even, Christmas will come early for you later on. Instead use MCBs. They can handle large current flows since theyre used in Power Grids and so on.

Comment: @Aaron I have mentioned current as 40A rms. Please let me know if u have any solution for the above query.

Comment: I am thinking to use Relay https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=T9G_1216&DocType=DS&DocLang=English.Here I think it can hold 40A rms current since we are not doing live switching. Also I am going to connect it in series to increase the switching voltage. I am now only concerned about the voltage rating of the contacts i.e. if i use SPDT, the ability to withstand the voltage across the pin when it is open (Not to melt the other side of the contact). Please let me know if this suits my application and to calculate the current carrying capacity of relay

Answer (score 1):

I found another way of diverting the power without using relays or switches or jumpers.

I am thinking of using Anderson powerpoles which is shown in the diagram.
It has a rating upto 150A and I just connect using this before i turn on the circuit.
I believe I can proceed with this so I put up this in an answer.

Comment: Manjesh Gowda - Hi, I recommend you delete your previous (now obsolete) version of the question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/536264) **immediately** (to avoid anyone trying to answer it). In general, you should have improved that *question* by editing it, instead of reposting a new version of the question. However in this case, that question has not received comments or answers, so just delete it - and please don't repeat questions in future. Instead, edit the original one to improve it. That is the Stack Echange methodology. More rules in the [tour] and [help]. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have deleted the question from your answer. It is only an answer, if you are not asking for advice - because if you ask for advice it becomes a *question* again, and questions are not allowed in the "answer box". If you want to ask about your proposed solution, then please delete the whole answer, move the proposed solution into the question, and ask about it there. Thanks.